# Significance label between two points along a scatter plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

My data:

```
structure(list(Point = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), 
    DF_FA_L = c(0.723876631, 0.736984528, 0.715005484, 0.689702567, 
    0.652340718, 0.602542524, 0.558524996, 0.515559258, 0.476045448, 
    0.440791984, 0.435388397, 0.433995996, 0.450236063, 0.461067635, 
    0.450821663, 0.406453595, 0.36881377, 0.368414258, 0.399242306, 
    0.434842762, 0.448778794, 0.450645853, 0.473092464, 0.502696464, 
    0.507365944, 0.498556214, 0.482145956, 0.458311758, 0.423308377, 
    0.385789401, 0.362710119, 0.351632877, 0.336368766, 0.327589544, 
    0.322429925, 0.319228948, 0.324069718, 0.335910091, 0.344128766, 
    0.361908972, 0.377642905, 0.382828373, 0.38802394, 0.385629004, 
    0.376905508, 0.365854595, 0.354565575, 0.346827766, 0.340045925, 
    0.344910972, 0.714518667, 0.728961368, 0.701283807, 0.663229965, 
    0.613014667, 0.547104, 0.504106246, 0.487034053, 0.451825246, 
    0.442370175, 0.438668316, 0.450059526, 0.478947649, 0.481134439, 
    0.446763544, 0.396206754, 0.357049368, 0.343943632, 0.376060404, 
    0.413613877, 0.434964895, 0.451208632, 0.470569193, 0.515300737, 
    0.543379719, 0.550050702, 0.541725807, 0.517293316, 0.485205246, 
    0.438844404, 0.395223491, 0.374209193, 0.354036316, 0.340668123, 
    0.326388667, 0.328114842, 0.342721667, 0.357620474, 0.372856842, 
    0.377362316, 0.393890737, 0.419330684, 0.419797667, 0.423127684, 
    0.421407509, 0.403711632, 0.39075314, 0.373226596, 0.348689877, 
    0.329466947), DF_FA_R = c(0.279912032, 0.306765439, 0.327785755, 
    0.355029826, 0.393800091, 0.44807915, 0.500145704, 0.52518085, 
    0.513479676, 0.498788964, 0.471167874, 0.444077727, 0.405423269, 
    0.374111696, 0.336296723, 0.290903704, 0.245428277, 0.207306561, 
    0.192131277, 0.193623134, 0.218199818, 0.242609257, 0.275690593, 
    0.305088802, 0.340290617, 0.380668937, 0.407181352, 0.427695356, 
    0.452447949, 0.449012126, 0.426914032, 0.400893245, 0.365861043, 
    0.345163874, 0.324515277, 0.305764024, 0.298522166, 0.298830834, 
    0.301616281, 0.304933115, 0.303430024, 0.307914826, 0.329325708, 
    0.349910727, 0.35703696, 0.352538779, 0.345419684, 0.338729395, 
    0.331719186, 0.334689565, 0.293618667, 0.30652786, 0.323910193, 
    0.334828491, 0.37942207, 0.428091754, 0.455930368, 0.478020105, 
    0.484362053, 0.501357439, 0.482654246, 0.490658667, 0.488896421, 
    0.471009596, 0.451751193, 0.443464982, 0.423077596, 0.405938053, 
    0.371860298, 0.342142386, 0.355380404, 0.336650965, 0.306194123, 
    0.307005667, 0.331578158, 0.393752421, 0.428736263, 0.434643421, 
    0.471135439, 0.485811825, 0.490740421, 0.464038193, 0.436188053, 
    0.381632737, 0.330827035, 0.302487754, 0.289443614, 0.295707035, 
    0.310712982, 0.320383877, 0.316538596, 0.333027772, 0.349954807, 
    0.368749877, 0.370285947, 0.369342158, 0.364773474, 0.368712281, 
    0.354579614, 0.355067965), DF_RD_L = c(0.00128287, 0.001346415, 
    0.001389324, 0.00139913, 0.001387198, 0.001263581, 0.001176972, 
    0.001140379, 0.001122925, 0.001084178, 0.001079348, 0.00108896, 
    0.001085937, 0.001103557, 0.001123668, 0.00108613, 0.00107296, 
    0.001127423, 0.001197549, 0.001237273, 0.001338632, 0.00140204, 
    0.001453071, 0.001519708, 0.001549107, 0.00155198, 0.00150604, 
    0.001412095, 0.001324316, 0.001200802, 0.001097542, 0.001016119, 
    0.000963012, 0.000931372, 0.000900976, 0.000881988, 0.000850344, 
    0.000821751, 0.000819154, 0.000832779, 0.000848632, 0.000855727, 
    0.000886138, 0.000928174, 0.000967573, 0.000993269, 0.00102087, 
    0.001044502, 0.001108162, 0.001147996, 0.001030544, 0.001002509, 
    0.000955719, 0.000960175, 0.000929596, 0.000859965, 0.000856088, 
    0.000872825, 0.000891491, 0.000911193, 0.000971596, 0.000966702, 
    0.000929737, 0.000848895, 0.00084314, 0.00090893, 0.000922965, 
    0.000901526, 0.000897684, 0.000943158, 0.001035895, 0.001122333, 
    0.001116579, 0.001220842, 0.001180579, 0.001107, 0.000939316, 
    0.000837246, 0.000755596, 0.000709491, 0.000701351, 0.00068907, 
    0.000685053, 0.000695982, 0.000714667, 0.000748246, 0.000763649, 
    0.000784035, 0.000780456, 0.000785526, 0.000883333, 0.000923246, 
    0.000973, 0.000999053, 0.000966965, 0.000956228, 0.000990807, 
    0.001019947, 0.001032, 0.001015088), DF_RD_R = c(0.001482767, 
    0.001472708, 0.001472478, 0.00144036, 0.001390383, 0.001321597, 
    0.001184138, 0.001090482, 0.001036292, 0.000992798, 0.00100483, 
    0.001011154, 0.001038285, 0.001050253, 0.001042162, 0.001114103, 
    0.001193858, 0.001285597, 0.001391779, 0.001459791, 0.001526862, 
    0.001556233, 0.0015487, 0.001586964, 0.001553826, 0.001558518, 
    0.001608079, 0.001625, 0.001649866, 0.001597375, 0.001556644, 
    0.001644312, 0.001805107, 0.001960146, 0.002029423, 0.002055767, 
    0.002054854, 0.002002909, 0.001907099, 0.001820692, 0.001730158, 
    0.001669328, 0.001597581, 0.001507957, 0.001395277, 0.001349368, 
    0.001355585, 0.001372605, 0.001353186, 0.001293146, 0.001227825, 
    0.001200614, 0.001173175, 0.001147842, 0.001152842, 0.001008702, 
    0.00098614, 0.001007509, 0.000980421, 0.000940018, 0.000966193, 
    0.00101586, 0.000984737, 0.000933228, 0.000892789, 0.000954667, 
    0.001052895, 0.001099088, 0.001107298, 0.001228842, 0.001332491, 
    0.001425088, 0.001486649, 0.001470333, 0.001509263, 0.001441, 
    0.001411895, 0.001404947, 0.001355175, 0.001309789, 0.001320947, 
    0.001307368, 0.001367386, 0.001385386, 0.001371596, 0.001356842, 
    0.001350632, 0.001298965, 0.001209105, 0.001162, 0.001164649, 
    0.001150386, 0.001157684, 0.001149298, 0.001122561, 0.00106893, 
    0.001050825, 0.001104351, 0.001050544, 0.001091544), AgeGroup = c("Old", 
    "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", 
    "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", 
    "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", 
    "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", 
    "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", 
    "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
    "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
    "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
    "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
    "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
    "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
    "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
    "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

Plotting some data of interest:

```
Myplot <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Point, y = DF_FA_L, color = AgeGroup)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=AgeGroup))
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

My interest is getting an * printed over each value as appropriate, to visualize which two points are significantly different from each other.

Currently, to get significant values between each point, I run a t-test with the raw-data set and then plot the p-values on the same x-axis.

**SAMPLE of raw data set**

```
structure(list(ID = c(5356L, 5357L, 5358L, 5359L, 5360L, 5363L
), sex = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L), AgeGroup = c("Old", "Old", 
"Old", "Old", "Old", "Old"), P1 = c(0.846218, 0.818277, 0.394048, 
0.817749, 0.459284, 0.818235), P2 = c(0.749018, 0.762768, 0.641596, 
0.778927, 0.742783, 0.78261), P3 = c(0.85127, 0.778184, 0.755854, 
0.75728, 0.661668, 0.797338), P4 = c(0.844308, 0.779024, 0.689351, 
0.650052, 0.783829, 0.730145), P5 = c(0.787763, 0.697728, 0.668848, 
0.730858, 0.692566, 0.708917), P6 = c(0.532558, 0.639361, 0.701394, 
0.658054, 0.655189, 0.653637), P7 = c(0.538886, 0.563347, 0.563391, 
0.582696, 0.579147, 0.589373), P8 = c(0.612433, 0.525205, 0.52012, 
0.495403, 0.479324, 0.379151), P9 = c(0.610298, 0.458874, 0.512224, 
0.364992, 0.446096, 0.415491), P10 = c(0.610437, 0.443188, 0.508442, 
0.326629, 0.368318, 0.400495), P11 = c(0.582697, 0.436657, 0.367942, 
0.419647, 0.509359, 0.359965), P12 = c(0.418116, 0.406218, 0.432974, 
0.536345, 0.384733, 0.413433), P13 = c(0.335965, 0.367993, 0.477519, 
0.560785, 0.45537, 0.48867), P14 = c(0.337992, 0.486724, 0.54703, 
0.58446, 0.483832, 0.597846), P15 = c(0.515328, 0.496987, 0.487978, 
0.424243, 0.346461, 0.628548), P16 = c(0.290485, 0.296858, 0.546061, 
0.407782, 0.363341, 0.440781), P17 = c(0.345598, 0.339083, 0.389276, 
0.367848, 0.456301, 0.494254), P18 = c(0.555913, 0.338544, 0.289163, 
0.423237, 0.35898, 0.273942), P19 = c(0.458874, 0.448812, 0.383933, 
0.534538, 0.428785, 0.372345), P20 = c(0.467797, 0.449758, 0.417042, 
0.526268, 0.517699, 0.542448), P21 = c(0.484283, 0.341703, 0.489561, 
0.488149, 0.492702, 0.574437), P22 = c(0.52395, 0.461447, 0.393448, 
0.478467, 0.462262, 0.684624), P23 = c(0.483296, 0.532121, 0.362841, 
0.571371, 0.501969, 0.589329), P24 = c(0.401993, 0.289979, 0.507893, 
0.54272, 0.582495, 0.569918), P25 = c(0.321685, 0.365791, 0.627645, 
0.551962, 0.49566, 0.666437), P26 = c(0.269855, 0.316144, 0.530101, 
0.531981, 0.485203, 0.523233), P27 = c(0.230605, 0.330686, 0.53342, 
0.523332, 0.416405, 0.497638), P28 = c(0.330101, 0.394783, 0.490131, 
0.42861, 0.365622, 0.488487), P29 = c(0.337178, 0.352451, 0.444646, 
0.459683, 0.322466, 0.430228), P30 = c(0.258203, 0.448741, 0.256495, 
0.431901, 0.294633, 0.358938), P31 = c(0.251116, 0.320609, 0.229432, 
0.38704, 0.352998, 0.307074), P32 = c(0.232901, 0.328501, 0.324575, 
0.347392, 0.320678, 0.348555), P33 = c(0.253213, 0.297051, 0.229997, 
0.25181, 0.280018, 0.401357), P34 = c(0.213982, 0.294554, 0.231242, 
0.307669, 0.306246, 0.326005), P35 = c(0.224542, 0.351411, 0.232466, 
0.287418, 0.328158, 0.292336), P36 = c(0.296813, 0.360996, 0.216996, 
0.257623, 0.34479, 0.337268), P37 = c(0.374465, 0.404577, 0.234981, 
0.289122, 0.297555, 0.329936), P38 = c(0.368419, 0.493077, 0.341728, 
0.319635, 0.310216, 0.31797), P39 = c(0.344618, 0.422014, 0.344069, 
0.393116, 0.317624, 0.315584), P40 = c(0.354358, 0.374753, 0.329991, 
0.394953, 0.320049, 0.318013), P41 = c(0.403487, 0.295078, 0.517829, 
0.468743, 0.394567, 0.330027), P42 = c(0.381721, 0.278112, 0.401598, 
0.394999, 0.402283, 0.313942), P43 = c(0.298645, 0.242265, 0.431335, 
0.472077, 0.387318, 0.308056), P44 = c(0.250141, 0.241611, 0.486916, 
0.402863, 0.371897, 0.357648), P45 = c(0.34065, 0.260425, 0.412001, 
0.365537, 0.317708, 0.284206), P46 = c(0.223116, 0.252645, 0.339408, 
0.489459, 0.302774, 0.283245), P47 = c(0.208375, 0.309779, 0.312521, 
0.448492, 0.303502, 0.303485), P48 = c(0.189177, 0.367197, 0.296298, 
0.372935, 0.34973, 0.306106), P49 = c(0.127422, 0.277153, 0.243066, 
0.356067, 0.360099, 0.216733), P50 = c(0.164432, 0.391867, 0.249639, 
0.364488, 0.347897, 0.312913)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

T-test:

```
rawDF_tTest = lapply(rawDF_tTest [c(-1,-2,-3)], function(x) t.test(x ~ AgeGroup, data = rawDF_tTest , rate = 0.1, var.equal = T))
rawDF_tTest = data.frame(do.call(rbind, rawDF_tTest ))
```

Then to plot:

```
# color pallete
 myPalette <- colorRampPalette(c("firebrick","orange","yellow1","turquoise4"))

ggplot(rawDF_tTest , aes(x = 1:50, y =log10(as.numeric(rawDF_tTest $p.value)))) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = as.numeric(rawDF_tTest $p.value)), size = 3) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100), limits=c(-0.01, 1))
```

Which comes out: 
[image]

I would like to know if I can use the t-test values to just plot everything on one graph?

Comment: You could add two other variables to your plotting data: 1) y-axis location of a significance symbol (e.g. asterisk), e.g. just a DF_FA_L + 0.05, 2) the significance symbol shape (smaller than alpha would be asterisk, greater than alpha would be NULL). You could then plot that on top of your graph. The question is though whether t-test may be the best statistical test for you, given that you do seem to have some time-dependence and hierarchical structure in your data. If you explain your data to me, I might be able to point you towards a better model.

Comment: @AdamB. so like this: ```ggplot(DF, aes(x = Point, (y = DF_FA_L+ 0.05, 2), color = AgeGroup)) + geom_point(aes(shape=AgeGroup)) ``` ?

The data is MRI data across young and old adults at specific voxels. For simplicity, I have 50 averaged voxels per subject across age groups. I chose t-test based on a publication doing similar work.

Comment: With this sort of data, you'd be much better off to use some sort of mixed effects model (because of Simpson's paradox - if you see some pattern across people, i.e. in average, it could be completely different within people, or vice versa). That way, you wouldn't have to take any averages, and your test would be more powerful and have adequately-controlled type-I error rate. I'd recommend checking out the `brms` package, it's relatively easy to fit some really cool models with it: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_overview.pdf.

Comment: But if you really wanna do t-test, then first take your df and create the new variables.: `DF %>% mutate(signif_y = DF_FA_L + 0.05, signif_s = ifelse(p.value < 0.05, "asterisk", "n")`. After that, you can use your code for the first plot to add the significance points.

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of time, I will apply t-test now but will look into mixed models as well.

Comment: @AdamB. I added a column to the DF with either ```*``` or ```-``` and I'm still struggling to plot both the main plot (plot 1) and significance values over the x-axis. Any tips?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner, try adding: `+ geom_point(aes(y = signif_y, shape = signif_s))` to your plot